# Asp.net Webgrid displays Microsoft.CRM.SDK.Money instead of the value

Tags: crm

I have put some sitesetting code in CRM  to extract some data and display it on a ASP.NET website webgrid.
Everything works fine, but one column of money does not display the value but rather: `Microsoft.XRM.SDK.Money`, I want the real value to be displayed.

My code:

```
<WebGridColumn Name="betrag" DataMember="betrag" Position="7"
        Caption="Betrag"  Width="100" />
```

I tried to do something with datatype and dataformat but it did't work.

Here is a picture of the output that I get, I want the real value displayed where it says `Microsoft.XRM.SDK.Money`

[image: Picture of column showing variable name, rather than value]

Answer (score 0):

Money is an object, if you want to know the value you need to access to its `.Value` because if has more atrributes like the currency.

Comment: Hello and thank you for answering me, I am quite beginner in programming, how do you suggest I modify my code ?

Comment: Can you write all the code so I can see what are you retrieving.